# How can I move some configuration parameters into the external js file and include it into the Gulpfile.js?

Tags: gulp

I’d like share my `Gulpfile.js` through several projects but still be able to customize the process with an external configuration file varying from one project to another.

What options do I have to achieve it? I can’t find it in docs.

Let's say I have such a file with two variables:

**my-config.js**

```
var serverRoot = 'app';
var serverPort = 8082;
```

I want to include `my-config.js` into the `Gulpfile.js` and use these variables in it:

**Gulpfile.js**

```
// somehow include my-config.js here...

var
    gutil = require('gulp-util');

gutil.log(serverRoot);
gutil.log(serverPort);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do like this:
**my-config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  serverRoot: 'app',
  serverPort: 8082
}
```

Or with **my-config.json**

```
{
   "serverRoot": "app",
   "serverPort": 8082
}
```

**Gulpfile.js**

```
var config = require('./my-config.js');
// or require('./my-config.json');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');

gutil.log(config.serverRoot);
gutil.log(config.serverPort);
```

Here is a [gist](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/using-external-config-file.md)

Comment: Thanks so much :))